# Aligning an edge to match another edge

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I'm new to QGIS and I wonder whether there is a tool that helps to adjust the edges between two or more polygons; similar to that topology tool that's used in ArcGIS.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/aligning-an-edge-to-match-another-edge.htm

---

I’m searching for an equivalent to the following tool (see link):

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/aligning-an-edge-to-match-another-edge.htm

Comment: "... adjust the edges ..." is a rather broad term.  Can you be more specific?  Screenshots would be very helpful.

Comment: OP most probably means that the boundaries between adjacent polygons should share exactly the same vertices and match topologically without any gaps or overlaps.

Answer (score 7):

In QGIS, this feature is called [Topological Editing](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing).

In the Snapping Toolbar, `enable topological editing`.

[image]

With topological editing enabled, when you use the Vertex Tool to move a vertex on one polygon, the same vertex on an adjacent polygon will also be moved, thus keeping the shared boundary.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try [v.edit](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.edit.html):

> Edits a vector map, allows adding, deleting and modifying selected
>   vector features.

With tool snap and a threshold distance:

[image]

I had to set output type `area` under Advanced parameters to get it to run